# R editing dataframe based on column value

Tags: r, data-science, data-scrubbing

Suppose I have a table of around 1M rows with the following format:

```
id  paid_2000  paid_2001  paid_2002  paid_2003  censor_yr
1   10         20         10         20         2001
2   15         25         15         15         2003
```

What would be an efficient way to set each observation to NA where the paid year is greater than or equal to the censor year?  In particular, I would like the table to look like this:

```
id  paid_2000  paid_2001  paid_2002  paid_2003  censor_yr
1   10         NA         NA         NA         2001
2   15         25         15         NA         2003
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  gather(paid_yr, value, grep("paid", names(.))) %>%
  mutate(value = ifelse(as.numeric(gsub(".*_", "", paid_yr)) >= censor_yr, 
                        NA, value)) %>%
  spread(paid_yr, value)
```

Throw a `%>% select` chain at the bottom to move `censor_yr` back to the end.

Can explain how it works if you'd like.  May or may not be easier to read than akrun's answers.

Answer (score 0):

We create an index of columns that are 'paid' ('pi'), subset the columns using 'pi', create a matrix of logical values by comparing the year substring from the column names of the 'paid' column with that of 'censor_yr' column and assign it to NA.

```
pi <- grep("paid", names(df1))
df1[pi][matrix(as.numeric(sub(".*_", "", names(df1)[pi]))[col(df1[pi])] >=
                       df1$censor_yr, nrow=2)] <- NA
df1
#   id paid_2000 paid_2001 paid_2002 paid_2003 censor_yr
#1  1        10        NA        NA        NA      2001
#2  2        15        25        15        NA      2003
```

---

Or we can do this in `data.table` `set` which would be more efficient.  Get the year substring from the `names` of the 'paid' column names, convert to `data.table` (`setDT(df1)`), loop through the columns in 'pi' and `set` the values to NA which meets the condition in 'i'.

```
library(data.table)
nm1 <- as.numeric(sub(".*_", "", names(df1)[pi]))
setDT(df1)
for(j in seq_along(pi)){
   set(df1, i = which(nm1[j] >= df1$censor_yr), j= pi[j], value = NA)
}
```